Quantile regression with a pre-existing cutoff point in the raw score of dependent variable
This is probably a dumb question, but I have never used quantile regression so I'm unsure.
I have the following situation: there is a continuous, numerical self-report measure with a certain, pre-established cutoff point at 100 points. Based on previous research it is considered that those who score lower than 100 do not have a certain "condition" and those who score 100 or above have it. My colleagues would like to run a model predicting this score from certain independent variables, but they would like to see whether predictors are related to the score differently for those scoring lower vs. higher than 100.
I previously got advice here suggesting that quantile regression would work, and I agree. But I'm not sure how to specify the quantiles. Clearly, I would need to specify (at least) 2 quantiles, to get the predictions for those who have the conditions and for those who don't have it, but how would I choose them? Should I check what quantile corresponds to the raw score of 100 in the sample, and then...somehow...choose one quantile a bit below the "100 quantile" and one a bit above the "100 quantile"? But how much below and above? How should I choose the exact quantiles?
(Those running the study prefer just two levels of predictions (two quantiles) because of previous work saying 100 is an important cutoff, and also to keep things simple.)

Instead of a regression why don't you run a classifier (XGBoost eg.)? As long as the prediction is Binary (<100 or >100) it should work.

Thanks for the idea, but we would like to predict the outcome as continuous below and above the cutoff point. Or is that how classifiers also work?

Cutoffs are always dubious, because nature rarely jumps. That said, I don't quite see why quantile regression would be useful here. I would simply predict this measure, period. You may have nonlinearities in the relationship between predictors and the measure (which may have to do with a change near 100, but we don't know whether a specific individual is above that threshold, that's what we want to predict!), which you could model using splines.

@StephanKolassa thank you, and I agree. The trouble is that in this field the 100 is considered a clear cutoff point and those collecting the data would like to get coefficients for below and above (an additional issue is they should run the analyses themselves and I'm pretty sure they cannot learn how to use splines very quickly). I would also personally like to know in general how to choose the quantiles in a situation like this (if we were to assume that in some cases a clean cutoff exists).

Hm. I still don't see how quantile regression would help. Like AT ALL. Is it that only 20% of the population are above the threshold? Or 80%? Here is an alternative: in your training data, fit one model A to predict the measure on instances where the measure is above the threshold. Train another model B to predict it on instances below the threshold. Finally, train a classifier C to predict whether any given instance is above or below the threshold. In predicting, use C first, and then pick either A or B depending on the output of C. Note this.

OK thank you, the training alternative sounds good, though I'm even less familiar with it than with splines, but live and learn..

I agree with @StephanKolassa but you write "they should run the analyses themselves".  Maybe they shouldn't. This desire is not limited to your case, but should be resisted.

Thank you all. I will consider alternative methods. Still, and I understand this is not the solution in the current situation, but if anyone has insight on choosing quantile levels in quantile regression, I'd like to know about that, just for my own education.

Since the cutoff of 100 was not validated, it is inappropriate to run analyses using it.  To validate a cutoff you’d need to show that the relationship between the underlying continuous variable and some “ultimate” outcome variable is flat on either side of the cutoff, i.e., that for each side of the cutoff there is complete homogeneity.

@FrankHarrell the data is not directly from my domain, but the understanding of those who have collected it (and have subject knowledge) seems to be that such validation has been done (against some type of "ultimate" outcome variable). I'm fairly sure this validation doesn't meet the criteria you mentioned though.

I'm pretty sure also.  In that case the dichotomization is likely defective and analyses using it are hard to interpret and lack power.

@Sointu justfor the record, you could use softmax function in order to find the probability that someone could be in the specified quantile (meaning the <100 and >100). However this is NOT the actual value you want to predict. I agree with a different approach in that case, using a regression (probably Stephan Kolassa's comment describes the most holistic approach).
